# What is good resource to take a look on puppet code?

Tags: deployment, automation, puppet

Is there something like Chef's open recipes on github which is recognized by community?

I am starting building system with puppet, but tutorials are not enough and stuff on github is in the late stages of development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Forge - http://forge.puppetlabs.com.

Although a lot of the modules on GitHub are complete too.

Comment: wow, is it really you? I got answer from puppet pro him self :) Thanks!

Comment: Heh. No problems - feel free to ping me if you can't find a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [United States Government Configuration Baseline manifests](http://usgcb.nist.gov/usgcb/rhel/download_rhel5.html) as well.